# Traveling from heathrow UK with baby food glass jars

Tags: uk, luggage, check-in

We are going to visit India next month, we are planning to take baby food in jars which are glass made.

We are not sure where to put them, whether in the main lauggage which will be booked on air line counter or in hand carry with us.

We will also have baby milk which we are not sure should whether go in main luggage or hand carry.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at airport rules such as those for [Heathrow](http://www.heathrow.com/more/help-with-this-website/faqs/security-and-baggage)

> **Can I carry liquid baby food, prepared milk, soya milk, rice milk or
> sterilised water through security?**
> Yes, if you are travelling with a
> baby or infant **you can carry a reasonable amount of liquid and
> liquidised food for the baby or infant infant for your journey**. To
> assist security screening, please do not carry these items in a flask.
> **Spare supplies must be packed in your hold baggage**.
>
> You can either
> carry the liquids as part of your liquid bag allowance in which case
> the standard liquid rules apply or alternatively separately in
> containers over 100ml. Following x-ray screening, security officers
> may also need to carry out additional checks on these items.

If you are intending to carry supplies to last longer than those required for the flight, it is likely you will have to pack these extra items in your checked-in luggage depending on the airports you are travelling from or through.

Comment: Often babyfood jars are quite small. If you have some that are 100ml or less you can add them to your liquids bag, in which case they count as normal liquids.

Comment: @Willeke Good point. I got the impression the OP is planning on carrying a supply for the whole trip but I could be mistaken

Comment: I feel that same, but spreading the load in hand luggage and hold luggage would be good. Smaller jars with liquids and some bigger jars for the flight